# Converting Single Page Application to Multi Page website with node.js and backbone.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backbone.js, requirejs

I have build a website where the contents are being transferred dynamically, with `nodejs` and `expressjs` with `jade` template engine, on the back end providing the REST API and `backbone.js` managed with `require.js`, using the `underscore` templates on the front end.

Contents are like Questions and Answers OR a review post about a product. Currently i am sending all these content as `JSON` and the Front end receiving `view` of `backbone.js` has the necessary javascript and the correct underscore templates to render the final html on the page.

This is fine when these content are to be seen as a feed, which get dynamically loaded on scroll.

But i want to have an separate page for each of these posts, like a separate page for a Question and related answer and a separate page for a review. I want these pages to be efficiently indexed by Search Engines, so i want to transfer them as the finally generated `HTML`, rather than a require.js main entry with contents getting populated after a series of ajax call.

One way to solve this is by using the express.js views to build the html on the server side and then inject all the necessary javascript in it and send it. But i don't want to repeat my logic.

I there any way that i can re-use the code logic written in backbone.js for template rendering with supplied variables and injection of js, all this on the server side and then simple send the generated final html to the client, so that if they see the source code of the page, they can see the full content.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are rendering on the server-side, one way to proceed is to bind the view to an element:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#yourSuperId"
});

new View();
```

Using the `el` property, you can automatically attach the view to the existing element. You don't need to render it.

Comment: This is something that is done on the client side. this code is run under backbone.js when a view is executed in the browser. But i want to do this on the server side. that means i have to run this code on the server-side. any leads in terms of how can i run backbone.js code on the server-side will be very helpful. thanks

Comment: You cannot run backbone on server-side, that would make no sense. But NodeJS provides templating engines (like Jade) to render server-side, then you can bind your view on it as I've explained.